# Mysql AES_ENCRYPT SHOW ONLY BYTES

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT AES_ENCRYPT('mytext', 'mykeystring')
```

Always shows results of

```
AES_ENCRYPT('mytext', 'mykeystring')
```

with size of 16 bytes.

How to get encrypted value instead of 16 bytes?

Comment: What do you mean by "encrypted value"? The byte string you get is the cypher text of the input.

Comment: Like this 5155969D3D2C647C28614542DF783329

Comment: You should not use AES_Encrypt in MySQL 8 or below. [Read why](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45838/is-why-should-you-avoid-aes-in-mysql-true).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the hexadecimal representation of the cipher text use `hex()`.

```
SELECT hex(aes_encrypt('mytext', 'mykeystring'));
```